# minitoc.sty file not found

Tags: minitoc

I'm using Ubuntu 16 as OS and Kile to compile my tex files, recently I used `minitoc` package but I got always the same error !

```
! LaTeX Error: File `minitoc.sty' not found.
```

Thanks for your help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install texlive-latex-extra package

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

this collection of packages that will be downloaded contains the desired file

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the `apt` package that contains a given file with

```
apt-file find "minitoc.sty"
```

If you’re willing to use up several gigabytes of disk space, you can run

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

This will install all TeX Live packages, and practically any document you might download will compile.

In rare cases, a file you need might not be available in any Debian or Ubuntu package.  Then, you will need to copy it to your project folder, or a subdirectory of your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory if you want to install it.  You can find this with

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

It is likely to be `/usr/share/texmf/` on your system.  You can put things other than 8-bit fonts in `TEXMFHOME`, but creating a font map as a user will cause problems.

If you want to use newer versions of the packages, and have full control over what to install, you can remove the system texlive and [do a custom installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553305/61644) to `/usr/local/texlive/`.